Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence, $a_n\to0$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=\infty$, what about $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n$?

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence and $a_n\to0$,
what about the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n\ .$$

Some progress to show my attempts:
It is easy to know $a_n\geq0,\forall n\in\mathbb N$.
First, If $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n<\infty$$ is convergent, then wen can get(Prove via contraposition that if $(a_n)$ is decreasing and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$) $$\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0;$$
Second, if $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=\infty$$
is divergent, I'm stuck in this case. But the following two cases can happen:
(1) if take $a_n=1/n$, we know $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=1$;
(2) if take $a_n=\frac{\log n}{n}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=\infty$.
I want to know if there is other case may happen or it is must be
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=a\in\mathbb R\quad \text{or}\quad \infty.$$
Added: What I concern more is the case for which the limit does not exist! Can someone give an example or prove that the limit must exist or is $\infty$.
Any comments and hints will welcome!

The sequence $n a_n$ might not converge at all. It might converge to zero. Can you find examples of each? Of course it can't converge to a negative number or to $-\infty$.

Taking something like $a_n=\frac{1}{n}(1 +\frac{1}{100} \sin(\pi n / 2))$ will have $n a_n$ oscillating around $1$. Verifying that $a_n$ is decreasing seems to be tedious though.

@
Eraser head when $n>2$, $(\log n)/n$ is decreasing.

@aschepler Can you give an example which is not convergent?

@
Eraser head
$n\cdot \frac{sin(\frac{1}{n})}{n}=sin(\frac{1}{n})\to0.$

$(n a_n)$ does not necessarily have a (finite or infinite) limit, one can construct a counterexample as follows:
Define the sequence $(b_n)$ by $b_1 = 1$ and
$$
 b_{n+1} = \begin{cases} 
   \frac{2n+1}{2n} b_n & \text{ if } b_n < 2 \, .\\
   1 & \text{ if } b_n \ge 2 \, .
\end{cases}
$$
Since $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n+1}{2n}$ diverges (see for example here), the second case occurs infinitely often, and we have
$$
 \liminf_{n \to \infty}\ b_n = 1,\qquad  
\limsup_{n \to \infty}\ b_n = 2 \, .
$$
Then $a_n = b_n/n$ converges to zero and is strictly decreasing, since
$$
 b_{n+1} < \frac{n+1}{n} b_n \implies a_{n+1} < a_n \,.
$$
But $n a_n = b_n$ does not converge to a finite value or to $+\infty$.

In a similar way one can construct an example with $\liminf n a_n = 0$ and $\limsup n a_n = \infty$.

Nice solution! Thank you very much.

Here's a ridiculous example:
For integers $a$ and $b$ with $a\leq b$ we will write $[a,b]$ for the set of integers $\{n\in\mathbb Z: a\leq n \leq b\}$. For any positive integer $n$, let $\pi_n = n^n$, so that $\pi_1=1, \pi_2=2^2=4, \pi_3=3^3=27,\ldots$.
Now if $n=\pi_k$ for some $k$, let $a_n = 1/\pi_k$. Otherwise there is a unique $k$ such that $n \in [\pi_k,\pi_{k+1}]$, and we let $a_n = 1/\pi_k$ if $k$ is even, or $a_n=1/\pi_{k+1}$ if $k$ is odd.
Thus $n=1=\pi_1$ so that $a_1=1$. Now $\pi_1<2<\pi_2=2^2=4$ and since $1$ is odd it follows $a_2=1/\pi_2 = 1/4$ and similarly $a_3=1/4$ while $n=4=\pi_2$ so that $a_n = 1/\pi_2$. Now $\pi_3= 27$, so $a_n = 1/4$ for all $n\in [4,26]$, while $a_{27}=1/27$, but then $a_{28} = 1/64$, since $\pi_3<28<\pi_4=64$ and $3$ is odd.
Now $na_n = 1$ whenever $n = \pi_k$ for some $k$. On the other hand, if $n=\pi_{2m-1}$ then
$$
\begin{split}
(n+1)a_{n+1} &= \frac{((2m-1)^{2m-1}+1)}{(2m)^{2m}} \\
&= (1-\frac{1}{2m})^{2m}.\frac{1}{2m-1} +\frac{1}{(2m)^{2m}} \\
&\simeq e^{-1}/2m
\end{split}
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\begin{split}
(n-1)a_{n-1} &= \frac{(2m-1)^{2m-1}-1}{(2m-2)^{2m-2}} \\
&= (1+\frac{1}{2m-2})^{2m-2}(2m-1) - \frac{1}{(2m)^{2m}}\\
&\simeq e(2m-1)
\end{split}
$$
where $n=\pi_k$ or $k$ is even and $n \in [\pi_{k-1},\pi_{k+1}]$. Then clearly $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence tending to zero, however the above shows that $(na_n)$ has $\liminf na_n=0$ and $\limsup na_n = \infty$.

I'm sorry, until now I did't understand your definition of $a_n$. For example, $a_1=1$, what is $a_2$? Can you explain you definition of $a_n$ ? Give more details! Thank you very much!

Updated my post to give more details, hopefully they help!

(+1) Not "ridiculous" at all.

@AnneBauval too kind! I guess somehow the example seemed silly because the sequence, rather than doing anything clever, is just very lazy: -- it stays still most of the time, then panics when it remembers it is supposed to be tending to zero and and jumps down a couple of orders of magnitude (at $\pi_{2k}-1$ to $\pi_{2k}$ and $\pi_{2k}+1$) but then does nothing for even longer.

Considering the title , we do not have to even consider $\Sigma$ & such.
Here are 3 Examples covering a wide range of "limits" :
(1) Converging to arbitrary number :
$$a_n=P/n :::: \lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=P$$
(2) Converging to $0$ :
$$a_n=P/n^2 :::: \lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$$
(3) Diverging to $\infty$ :
$$a_n=P/\sqrt{n} :::: \lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=\infty$$

Why remove the "Decreasing Criteria"?

We can see that $a_n=sin(n)$ is not "Decreasing" , hence we have to worry about $a_n=sin(n)/n$ going Positive & Zero & Negative. Examples 1,2,3 match what you want. Examples 4-5,6 might not have that "Decreasing Criteria" , we have to check with more work

I hope you can give an answer of my question! Thank you! Without Decreasing Criteria, this question is nothing!

I think I answered your question in the title ? In general , there is not much connection to the limit you want & the $\Sigma$ limit. It is unnecessary to even consider the unrelated $\Sigma$ limit.

Did you check Examples 1,2,3 ? Do you not agree with that ? Do those not match what you want ?

I can remove Examples 4,5,6 (which are additional learning material) if that is what you want.

I have give example $a_n=\frac1n,\frac{\log n}{n}$ , there is no essiential difference with your examples $1,2,3$.

What is the title of your Question ? Have I answered it ?

Actuall, your answer is nothing but only  my two examples!

Thank you for you attention for my question!  Stop here now!

OK , I now got what you are saying , I stopped reading when I saw $\Sigma$ which is totally unrelated to the title question. I gave Examples to cover all cases. Nothing more to consider. When you too remove that unrelated $\Sigma$ to update your Post , then it is self-answering.

YOU cover the case when  the limit does not exist???
